# Spinner data binding issue..

Tags: android

Hello i want to bind particular field 'location' from my table to spinner in android. This is my code.. Can anyone help me?

```
Cursor cur=db.getdata();
    String[] columns=new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_LOCATION};
    int[] to=new int[] {R.id.text_location};
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Next.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    SimpleCursorAdapter sc=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cur,columns,to,0);
    sc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(sc);
```

Comment: Elaborate your question that user can understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
int[] to=new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cursor cur=db.getdata();
 String[] columns=new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_LOCATION};
        int[] to=new int[] {R.id.text_location};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
            cur, 
            columns, 
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp.setAdapter(adapter );
```